# Typescript Angularjs Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am pretty new to Angular.JS and Typescript and try to use them together but I am stuck at a point, which should not be a problem for most of you.

Is successfully made route with a view and a controller.

This works perfectly if they are in the some file like this.

```
var collabClientApp = angular.module('collabClientApp', ['ui.router']);
console.log("started routing");

collabClientApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/projects");
  $stateProvider
    .state('projects', {
      url: "/projects",
      templateUrl: "views/projects.html",
      controller: "ProjectListController"
    })
});

collabClientApp.controller("ProjectListController",
  function ProjectListController($scope) {
    $scope.projects = projects;
  }
);
```

Then I tried to move the controller to a separate file like this:

```
/// <reference path="../controllers.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../collabClientApp.ts"/>

"use strict";

collabClientApp.controller("ProjectListController",
  function ProjectListController($scope) {
    $scope.projects = projects;
});
```

collabClientApp.ts is the name of the file which does the routing.
I get the following message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: collabClientApp is not defined
```

The reference part is correct, so collabClientApp should be found in the controller-file.
Or do I miss something?

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The files need to be loaded in the browser. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?hd=1&v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile with the --out option to get a single file. OR include all files using script tags OR use a module loader like RequireJS

Comment: Ah thanks. I must have overseen the tsc argument for generate one big file. Thanks for you help.